# Dynamically create tab in android and load fragment with parameters passed in it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-webview, android-tablayout

I want to create tabs dynamically on the basis of count of websites given in an array. On each click of tab I want to load a fragment with webview with website loaded in it by passing corresponding url of website from array. Can I implement pager in it too?

Thanks

---

I had posted a help request previously with my code at, or may be I was not able to define my problem there:
[Dynamically adding tabs in android with webview and fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790843/dynamically-adding-tabs-in-android-with-webview-and-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i ve done this long ago maybe few bugs but still:

Create arraylist of fragments and urls in mainactivity:

```
 ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<String> urls =  new ArrayList<>();
```

Now while u iterate through ur dynamic data keep adding:

```
 while(iterator.hasNext()) {
fragments.add(new ftab1());
urls.add(url);
}
```

Now setup adapter passing above two arraylist:

```
PagerAdapter pageradapter= new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext(),fragments,urls);
  pager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
```

Now coming to PagerAdapter:
Create two global variables

```
ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
    ArrayList<String> urls;
```

Define constructor and initialise the above 2 variables:

```
 public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments,ArrayList<String> urls) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.fragments = fragments;
        this.urls=urls;
    }
```

Now main function is getItem() pass data in bundle to that activity:

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("url",urls.get(i));
        fragments.get(i).setArguments(data);
        return fragments.get(i);
    }
```

Now get url in your ftab1 like this:

```
String url = getArguments().getString("url");
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to achieve the desired functionality. But xcept first tab others tab are throwing exceptions "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: @Programmer001 It is hard to tell without seeing your code , share your modified ftab1 code

Comment: @Programmer001 make sure you are linking your tablayout with viewpager like this `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that. Problem was at tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    }